# cakephp 2.10 model associations in three table

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have three table `users` and `user_categories` and `categories`

when create new user then user choose multiple category and selected categories save in user_categories with hashMany associations

How to get category details ?

Answer (score 1):

In your User model put

```
class User extends AppModel {
    public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
        'Category' => array(
            'joinTable' => 'user_categories',
         )
    );
}
```

then you can get user categories like this:

`$this->User->find('all', ['contain' => ['Category']]);`

https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#hasandbelongstomany-habtm

Answer (score 0):

There are below possibility to get the category detail on the user query giving by the appropriate relations:

```
// User.php
    class User extends AppModel {
         public $actsAs = array('Containable');
         public $hasMany = array(
              'UserCategory'
         );
}

//UserCategory.php
    class UserCategory extends AppModel {
         public $actsAs = array('Containable');
         public $belongsTo = array(
              'Category'
         );
}
//Category.php
    class Category extends AppModel {
         public $actsAs = array('Containable');
         public $hasMany = array(
              'UserCategory'
         );
}
```

So, if you want category data along with user, your query will be similar to:

**`$this->User->find('all',['contain'=>['UserCategory'=>['Category']]]);`**

Hope this will solve your concern.

Comment: JFYI,
With the above code have you added containable behaviour for the category model?